# How do I stop a uWSGI server after starting it?

Tags: pyramid, uwsgi

I have a Python pyramid application that I am running using uwsgi like so:

```
 sudo /finance/finance-env/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste-logged /finance/corefinance/production.ini
```

Once it's running and my window times out, I am unable to stop the server without rebooting the whole box. How do I stop the server?

Comment: You cannot stop Skynet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can kill `uwsgi` process using standard Linux commands:

```
killall uwsgi
```

or

```
# ps ax|grep uwsgi
12345
# kill -s QUIT 12345
```

The latter command allows you to do a graceful reload or immediately kill the whole stack [depending on the signal](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html) you send.

The method you're using, however, is not normally used in production: normally you tell the OS to start your app on startup and to restart it if it crashes. Otherwise you're guaranteed a surprise one day at a least convenient time :) Uwsgi docs have [examples](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html#starting-the-server) of start scripts/jobs for Upstart/Systemd.

Also make sure you don't really run uwsgi as root - that `sudo` in the command makes me cringe, but I hope you have `uid`/`gid` options in your `production.ini` so Uwsgi changes the effective user on startup. Running a webserver as root is never a good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, running the command without sudo gives me "bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 769]"

Comment: @JeremyT: you need to be `root` to bind to ports lower than 1024. In which case you need to make sure that uWSGI drops privileges after startup (i.e. it changes to a non-privileged userid) by specifying `uid` and `gid` options in the config or in the command line.

Comment: So, are you saying that it's better to try to figure out how to launch the process without using sudo, or that I should use sudo and instead set it to change users after startup?

Comment: If the server needs to listen on a port below 1024 you *have to* start it as root. But the app needs then to drop privileges (via the uid/gid parameters). I'm also suggesting to start the app via Systemd/Upstart, in which case you won't need `sudo` anyway.

Answer (score 9):

If you add a --pidfile arg to the start command

```
 sudo /finance/finance-env/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste-logged /finance/corefinance/production.ini --pidfile=/tmp/finance.pid
```

You can stop it with the following command

```
sudo /finance/finance-env/bin/uwsgi --stop /tmp/finance.pid
```

Also you can restart it with the following command

```
 sudo /finance/finance-env/bin/uwsgi --reload /tmp/finance.pid
```

Comment: superb! thanks a lot. Most of people forget to run this first command which uses the ini file configuration.  ```sudo /finance/finance-env/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste-logged /finance/corefinance/production.ini --pidfile=/tmp/finance.pid```

Comment: good to know: `--stop` command here is not graceful stop. `--reload` is graceful reload. more here: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/849